# Azure strange behaviour in AIP activity explorer

Tags: azure

The AIP activity explorer in compliance.microsoft.com started logging activities from outlook.office.com. It started 15.09, but I activated Azure RMS 16.09.
It started logging activities only when a user sends an email outside of the company.

Why is that ?

Comment: Are you really talking about AIP, or do you mean MIP? Maybe explain how you enabled "Azure RMS"

Comment: @Hupfauer I enabled it using a powershell command - Enable-AipService

Comment: @Hupfauer When I'm in the AIP activity explorer, it shows me emails sent outside, but only from outlook.office.com.  I even tried to disable the AipService, but I still get the same results.

Comment: @Hupfauer It seems like some update links some random data to the activity explorer as "Label applied" but the label isn't specified

Comment: The reason why I ask this is because Microsoft changed the whole ordeal regarding the labeling from AIP to what the now call is the [unified labeling platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/faqs#how-can-i-determine-if-my-tenant-is-on-the-unified-labeling-platform). The whole labeling system is very slow to react, it usually takes us somewhere between 24 - 48 h to see changes we made to labels. So I wouldn't be surprised that you don't see intimidate changes. Regarding the time: Microsoft sometimes messes up the time zones on these things, could this be true?

Comment: Oh and you should probably read [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/rms-client/use-client#choose-your-windows-labeling-solution)

Comment: @Hupfauer The problem is I didn't set any label or dlp rule that applies only to emails in outlook.office.com and only emails that go outside the organisation.